# Add the URL of home-page for "Add to home screen" on my site

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

In my website, I have several pages. When people tap on "add to home screen" on an iPhone device, they can save the icon on the phone like an app, but the icon opens that exact page.

Is there any way that when users bookmark any pages on my website, the shortcut on the phone always open my home page?

Is there a code that I can add to all the pages on my site to make it happen?

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to force all visitors to your set of pages to not be able to go directly to a page they want to visit, but always have to visit your primary page as a gateway?  If there is a 404 or some other error, you may be able to force that to redirect to your primary page as part of the HTTP server settings.

Comment: Not as of this response. Your question was addressed here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887676/can-the-url-for-the-add-to-home-screen-on-iphone-safari-be-customized